# Why jquery's mouseover() event occurred at inner element?

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have a question about mouseover and mouseout method of jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
#land {
    background: #FFCC33;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#water {
    background: #33CCCC;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

#island {
    background: #33FF33;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="land">
        <div id="water">
            <div id="island"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#land").on({
            "mouseover" : function() {
                console.log("land - mouse over");
            },
            "mouseout" : function() {
                console.log("land - mouse out");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

When mouse is move 'land' -> 'water' the mouse over event is occurred.
When 'water' -> 'island' mouse out and mouse over event is occurred.

Why mouse over event is occurred???

Comment: island element is contained in water element which is contained in land element, so actually you are doing a mouseover on land, water and island if you mouseover island

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) is defined, it is fired when you move to a descendant also and the bubbles so when the event is occurred in a descendant any handlers attached to the parent is fired.

> The mouseover event is fired when a pointing device is moved onto the
>   element that has the listener attached or onto one of its children.

If you don't want that to happen then use [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) events

> The mouseenter event is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse)
>   is moved over the element that has the listener attached. 
>   Similar to [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout), it differs in that it doesn't [bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.bubbles) and that it
>   isn't sent when the pointer is moved from one of its descendants'
>   physical space to its own physical space.

So when 'water' -> 'island'  occurs, a `mouseout` is fired by `water` and `mouseover` is fired by `island` and these events bubbles the handlers attached to `land` is fired.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#land").on('mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
     console.log(e.type, e.target.id)
   });
 });
```

```css
#land {
  background: #FFCC33;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#water {
  background: #33CCCC;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
#island {
  background: #33FF33;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="land">
  <div id="water">
    <div id="island"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```